# Is it possible to implement an equivalent of setTimeout() in javascript?

Tags: javascript, time, settimeout

Is it possible to implement a function equivalent of `setTimeout()` in JavaScript? If yes, what would be the best way to do that?

```
function setTimeout(callback, time_in_ms)
{
    // Implementation of time elapse of time_in_ms
    callback();
}
```

I am asking this question out of curiosity. A simple *"No, it is not possible"* would also be an enough answer to this question.

Comment: What? why don't you just use the existing one?

Comment: There wouldn't be one, unless you lock the thread that is

Comment: Please explain why. Sounds like an X/Y problem

Comment: You'd need very low level access to the timing thread, which I don't think you can get without using setTimeout, setInterval. So 1) this question is very strange 2) I don't beleive it would be possible. The issue with using a loop for this is that you'd lock the main UI thread which would defeat the object of having this

Comment: Please read [ask]. Key phrases: "Search, and research" and "Explain ... any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself".

Comment: @musefan could lock some worker thread and add callback on message from it.

Comment: If you're trying to make something like a `sleep()` function, you can't. In some JavaScript environments you could leverage facilities like web workers to kind-of do something similar to `sleep()`. It would be helpful to know why that would be preferable to just plain `setTimeout()` however.

Comment: @musefan, not entirely true, you could also use a loop of custom events or an requestAnimationFrame loop, though I wouldn't advise anyone to do so...

Comment: @Kaiido: well, if the solution allows to use built in functions, then just use the `setTimeout` function

Comment: @musefan sure, that's why I said not **entirely** true. The implementation of setTimeout is actually just *When you've got time, check if x time has elapsed, then execute fn*. So one *could* implement it with other built-in functions, but as I also said, *I wouldn't advise anyone to do so*, and I really don't see why OP needs it.

Comment: @mplungjan I don't see why he should explain why he wants to do that. In this case it doesn't even looks like a problem. More like a question about is it possible and if so how .. `Can I implement setTimeout() in javascript myself?` is the title and so the question

Comment: @caramba - it is always a good idea to explain. Perhaps he has some misunderstandings about what setTimeout does - for example his boss told him that it is like an eval and not allowed, then we could explain how to use an anonymous function instead.

Comment: @caramba: Because *we* are interested in knowing what insane reason he has for not using it, as we are all ready to jump on him and tell him how stupid the reason is the second he speaks of it

Comment: Just like askin "Can i implement `getElementById()` on my own?"

Comment: @Novice that's a very great example! Now you could implement it on your own (someone else also did it) just probably not in javascript. But for me it is an interesting question where Bergi down below got a great answer ...

Comment: Exactly! possible but not in javascript. You can just download and compile your custom V8 but then what is the use?

Comment: I didn't get you completely but yea this is life.

Answer (score 6):

> Can I implement `setTimeout()` in javascript myself?

No - not without some other natively asynchronous API. You might be able to implement it in terms of `setInterval`, with web workers, `requestAnimationFrame` or really anything that runs in the same event loop as `setTimeout` would. But if there is a reason that prevents you from using the builtin `setTimeout`, there probably are also other issues with your environment - so it depends on the specific situation.

Comment: Why would any of those methods be available, if `setTimeout` isn't?

Comment: @Cerbrus That I don't know, but I'm curious for the OP to elaborate on his scenario :-)

Comment: Taking into account the fact that the OP hasn't shown any signs of life since submitting the question, I doubt we'll ever know. Personally, I'd rather just get rid of the question. As it is right now, it's of no real value to SO.

Answer (score 2):

A synchronous (non-asynchronous) `setTimeout` equivalent would be something like this:

```js
function myTimeout(fun, milisecs) {
    var nowT = Date.now();
    while(Date.now()< nowT+milisecs){
      continue;
    }
    fun();
}
function consout() {
     console.log('The future arrived now!');
}

myTimeout(consout,2000);
```

However, as [Bergi mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40509649/6225838) you probably want an asynchronous API to avoid stalling the JavaScript execution of your browser.

A [Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) has multi-thread capabilities to allow this, with functions such as `myWorker.port.start()` and `myWorker.terminate()`... I have never needed to create something with Workers or similar APIs, but perhaps you may research a little bit more in this field (I also should not complete your homework, if that is the case).

Comment: That code is a "[Busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting)" implementation. That's a pretty bad idea, as it blocks _everything else_ from running. Basically, it's not a timeout, but a `wait` function that accepts an callback.

Comment: Thanks for the link @Cerbrus. I am aware of spinning, that's why I mentioned doing this synchronously would stall the Javascript execution of the browser... Which normally is a very bad idea as you mentioned.

Comment: This is a very clever solution..  I like how you can mixed while with date now to produce a psuedo `setTimeout()`.  I'm not sure other solutions but this might be the answer OP was looking for.